# Run Multiple Forms In Oracle 10g

Tags: forms, oracle, web, oracle10g

I want To Run Multiple Forms In Oracle 10g. But "formsweb.cfg" Settings Doesn't Allow Me To Do So. Right Now I Can Run Only One Form At A Time By Giving Its Path & Username/Password In "formsweb.cfg".
Can Anyone Provide Me A Better Solution For This Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create multiple sections in your formsweb.cfg

```
[config1]
...
[config2]
...
[config3]
...
```

Then you can start each forms config with

```
http://yourserver:1234/forms/servlet?config=config1   
http://yourserver:1234/forms/servlet?config=config2   
http://yourserver:1234/forms/servlet?config=config3
```

or config2 or config3